# File Formats getting lost in Beyond Compare

Tags: file-format, beyondcompare

I created some new file formats for Beyond Compare. They work just fine. However, whenever I close Beyond Compare, they disappear and I need to reimport the formats. The same thing happened with some formats that I downloaded from their site, so I know it's not an issue with the way I defined them.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You should email support@scootersoftware.com.  We have a very knowledgeable support staff.

Comment: I did. I was getting impatient waiting for my post to be moderated :)

Answer (score 1):

From the Beyond Compare [support team](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=13345):

> This can happen if your settings files are read-only.
>
> To check your settings, run Beyond Compare 3, then select "Help >
>   Support". Click the "Explore settings folder" link.
>
> File Formats are stored in the file "BCFileFormats.xml". Make sure
>   your user account has write access to this file, otherwise it won't
>   retain settings changes the next time you run Beyond Compare.